# Must I display Health and Mana to the player?

Tags: game-design, ui-design

I'm thinking of doing one or more of the following:

- hiding the player's Health
- hiding the player's Mana
- hiding the player's Health from other players
- hiding the player's Mana from other players

I don't know of any game that has done such things before so I'm wondering if this will have a positive effect on the players and why no game has done so before.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? What exactly is the game experience you want to achieve that way?

Comment: Simplicity. The player can focus on the battle (it's a 1v1 pvp game). Less cluttered screen.

Comment: Depending on your game, tactics may change based on the player viewing these numbers, therefore it may not be a good idea to hide them completely. You could perhaps have them visible for a short time when damage is taken or mana is used? It then becomes part of the game - the player has to pay attention to the values when they appear.

Comment: Several games exist that don't display a health count or bar, but instead give some other form of visual feedback when the player is injured; e.g. by tinting the screen progressively stronger shades of red as you take damage.

Comment: Does dead space's health on the spine armor count as hidden?

Comment: @Bálint I would say yes. Dead Space's UI is so well done. It's almost like an HUD but in game but it really fills as part of the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiding the player-character's (PCs) health actually got quite common in the FPS genre. Instead of showing a health number on the bottom of the screen, they represent the health state of the PC with a [meta-interface](http://devmag.org.za/2011/02/02/video-game-user-interface-design-diegesis-theory/). When the player is hurt, the screen gets a red tint or gets splattered with blood. This represent the pain the PC is experiencing.

The idea behind this is to make the game more immersive. Numbers on the user interface are often considered immersion-breaking because they are inherently non-diegetic. This is why some game designers try to minimize them as much as possible.

But hiding the exact health value is usually combined with quickly auto-regenerating health. The player doesn't *need* to know the PCs exact health, because it recovers so quickly anyway. But without quick health generation, health becomes a resource the player needs to manage. In order to manage a resource properly, the player must be able to check the exact number at any time.

Also, you must not forget to give *some* visual cue about the health state of the PC. When the player is completely unaware of it, they might not realize that their PC is almost dead, make a risky decisions and be surprised why they died so easily. This will be very frustrating for the player and might cause them to wonder if your damage calculation mechanics are buggy.

The same can be applied to mana. Provide some visual cue for the player how much mana their PC approximately has at the moment. Also, just like health, you should only do this when mana regenerates extremely fast. When mana is a resource the player needs to manage strategically, hiding it will be quite annoying for them.

Regarding hiding the opponent's health and/or mana: This is really just a question of how much information you want to hide. It is not uncommon for games to completely hide the enemy condition until they are defeated, but there are plenty of other examples of games which make the enemy condition transparent. Showing this information makes the game a bit more tactical (because the players have more information about who is currently winning a fight), while hiding that information makes the game more psychological (you have to guess the other character's status from the player behavior).

Comment: I still don't understand how blood splatters make the game more immersive. I don't think getting a hit in the leg gets blood on your eye

Comment: Do you have any examples of games that hide the opponent's condition?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Pretty much every first person shooter I can think of. But maybe we are not thinking about the same genres of games.

Comment: @Philipp Ah true. I wasn't thinking about FPS. Any other genre, like RPGs?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Most single player RPGs I can think of also usually hide enemy health. In the MMORPG genre it became general convention to give a health bar to mobs and sometimes also to opponents in PvP. But that wasn't always the case. The first MMORPG I ever played (Ragnarok Online) had no health bars for opponents, neither mobs nor in PvP.